# How to prevent Fluent NHibernate from adding "Parent" table's FK to relationship tables?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have the entities:

```
public class Plugin
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual int Version { get; set; }

    public virtual Plugin ParentPlugin { get; set; }
    public virtual IEnumerable<Setting> Settings { get; set; }
}
public class Setting
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Plugin Plugin { get; set; }
    public virtual int Version { get; set; }
}
```

The problems is that when I added ParentPlugin, it added a ParentPlugin_Id to the Setting table in the DB.  I can't figure out why it did this, however I'd like for Setting to only have a Plugin_Id not both Plugin_Id and ParentPlugin_Id in the database.

So, I would like to know 2 things to receive bounty:
1.  How can I remove the ParentPlugin_Id reference from Setting?
2.  And why did it do this in the first place (link to doc is ok, I could not find one explaining this)?

I'm using Fluent Nhibernate's automapping, mostly all defaults.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By specifying the exact FK name I was able to remove the extra ParentPlugin_Id.  A bit counter intuitive to have to add an FK instead of removing one but...

```
 .Override<Plugin>(m => m.HasMany(c => c.Settings).KeyColumn("Plugin_Id"))
```

This was figured out by a deeper understanding of the Foreign Key Conventions (https://github.com/jagregory/fluent-nhibernate/wiki/Auto-mapping)